# dijit.DateTextBox with dojox.widget.Calendar - initialisation

Tags: dojo

**Environment**: Dojo.1.8.4

If the DateTextBox does not contain a valid date, I wish to start the calendar popup at a date in the past (it's a date of birth entry box). What is the best way of achieving this?

```html
<div maxlength="12" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
    data-dojo-props="required: true, constraints:{min:'1880-01-01', 
        max: new Date()}, popupClass: 'dojox.widget.Calendar'">
</div>
```

I want to be able to put a 'startDate' parameter or similar in the above such that the constructor for the popup will pick it up and use it.

It looks as though the `dojox.widget._CalendarBase` sets the date to the current date in its constructor. (actually seems to set it in both the constructor and the declaration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to extend the dojox.widget.Calendar in order to accept the `currentFocus` passed by the popup. Like the `aspect` method above, it temporarily disables onChange in order to prevent the value being placed in the parent DateTextBox

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dojox/widget/Calendar"
], function(declare, calendar){
    return declare("my.dijit.Calendar", [calendar], {
        postCreate: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);

            var oldOnChange = this.onChange;
            this.onChange = function(){}; 

            this.set('value', this.parseInitialValue( this.currentFocus));

            this.onChange = oldOnChange;
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: If you are using the `dijit/Calendar` dropdown default then use the `dropDownDefaultValue` property as @vogomatix says in the other answer.

The following is if you are using the `dojox/widget/Calendar` for the dropdown.

---

By default the popup is set to the current value of the textbox and if null, it will use the current date.

You can do

1) set the value of the text box to what you want the default to be

OR

2) use aspects to set the value in the calendar when it is opened.

```javascript
require([
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/aspect',
    'dijit/form/DateTextBox',
    'dojox/widget/Calendar'
], function(dom, aspect, DateTextBox, Calendar){

    var dt = new DateTextBox({ popupClass: Calendar }, dom.byId('dtText'));

    aspect.after(dt, 'openDropDown', function() {

        // only default if there is no value
        if(dt.get('value') == null) {

            // Do not set the text box when changing value,
            // so temporarily override the onchange function
            var oldOnChange = dt.dropDown.onChange;
            dt.dropDown.onChange = function(){}; 

            dt.dropDown.set('value', new Date(1980, 7, 4)); // default to August 4th, 1980

            dt.dropDown.onChange = oldOnChange;
        }
    });    
});
```

See it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/kQYhQ/

Comment: There appears to be a `dropDownDefaultValue` attribute of the DateTextBox (`_DateTimeTextBox`) (which seems a simpler route if I can get it functioning! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that when looking at the source code.  It ends up setting that value to the currentFocus property.  Good find

Comment: You should add that as an answer to this question and accept it.

Comment: dojox.calendar.Widget does not support the currentFocus property which is what the dropdownDefaultValue gets set to.

Comment: Yep, I'd reached the same conclusion... did you find out by looking or from the manual/ web site?

Comment: Yes in order for it to work have to include some of your code into a postCreate function of an extended class...

Comment: Thanks for your help - i posted a second answer below, which used part of your answer to get round the currentFocus problem,

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set `dropDownDefaultValue`, which works with the standard calendar.

```
var dt = new DateTextBox({dropDownDefaultValue: new Date( 1950,1,1)},
     dom.byId('dtText'));
```

`dropDownDefaultValue` gets passed to the calender in the form of `currentFocus` by the popup. Unfortunately `dojox.widget.Calendar` does not recognise `currentFocus` and the way round that is to either extend the class to do so, or to use the aspect method above.